# Sorting ArrayList with Lambda in Java 8

Tags: java, lambda, functional-programming, java-8

Could somebody show me a quick example how to sort an `ArrayList` alphabetically in Java 8 using the new lambda syntax.

Comment: I suggest you to read this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html

Answer (score 74, accepted):

For strings this would work

```
arrayList.sort((p1, p2) -> p1.compareTo(p2));
```

Comment: Better: arrayList.sort(String::compareTo)

Comment: Even better: [`arrayList.sort(Comparator.naturalOrder())`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#naturalOrder--)

Comment: Note that both `.sort(String::compareTo) and .sort(Comparator.naturalOrder())` will sort **all** upper case letters before any lower case letters. Usually what you want is `.sort(String::compareToIgnoreCase)`

Answer (score 33):

Are you just sorting `String`s?  If so, you don't need lambdas; there's no point.   You just do

```
import static java.util.Comparator.*;

list.sort(naturalOrder());
```

...though if you're sorting objects with a `String` field, then it makes somewhat more sense:

```
list.sort(comparing(Foo::getString));
```

Answer (score 9):

Use `list.sort(String::compareToIgnoreCase)`

Using `list.sort(String::compareTo)` or `list.sort(Comparator.naturalOrder())` will give incorrect (ie. non-alphabetical) results. It will sort **any** upper case letter before **all** lower case letters, so the array `["aAAA","Zzz", "zzz"]` gets sorted to `["Zzz", "aAAA", "zzz"]`

Answer (score 8):

Suppose you have List of names(String) which you want to sort alphabetically.

```
List<String> result = names.stream().sorted(
                 Comparator.comparing(n->n.toString())).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

its working perfectly.

Comment: The `Comparator` is entirely unneeded.

Answer (score 4):

In functional programming, you're not using the old objects to operate on them, but creating the new one in such a fashion:

```
list.stream().sorted().map(blah-blah).filter(...)...
```

Comment: This is incorrect, as now the stream no longer consists of the old elements, but of the mapped and filtered version. Consider a bank account which you want to sort by person name: If you do it like you suggest, then you start of with a stream of bank accounts, and end up with a stream of person names, while you want to end up with a stream of bank accounts again.

Comment: Generally, when you write your programs in FP-style, you don't need to iterately save the results. So, this all is a **new** list(s): list.stream().sorted() is not sorting the old list, but creating the new one.

Comment: And that list has just became useless as you **only** have the person's name left (in my example), and you cannot reference it back (directly) to their bank account anymore.

Comment: Also, possibly a source of your confusion (nothing to blame), is that the OP requested a method to sort a list, yet you only return an intermediary stream, you also will need to store it at some point, which you omitted from your answer. By trying to implement that, you may see the issue yourself aswell.

Comment: If you **really** want to store the result in the same list, you can do something like: `list = list.stream().sort().collect(Collectors.toList());`, but again, author was requesting something in Java 8 style, and that's in Java 8 style.

Comment: You have now omitted specifying the sort-operator, please first get a working example, then update your answer with the working example.

Comment: @skiwi there's no need to specify the sort operator as OP wanted to sort `String`s in lexicographic order, it's the default behavior.

Answer (score 3):

Lambdas shouldn't be the goal. In your case, you can sort it the same way as in Java 1.2:

```
Collections.sort(list); // case sensitive
Collections.sort(list, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER); // case insensitive
```

If you want to do it in Java 8 way:

```
list.sort(Comparator.naturalOrder()); // case sensitive
list.sort(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER); // case insensitive
```

You can also use `list.sort(null)` but I don't recommend this because it's not type-safe.

Answer (score 2):

A really generic solution would be to introduce some `StreamUtil` like

```
public class StreamUtil {

    private StreamUtil() {
    }       

    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
    public static <TYPE> Comparator<TYPE> sort(Function<TYPE, ? extends Comparable> getterFunction, boolean descending) {
        if (descending) {
            return (o1, o2) -> getterFunction.apply(o2).compareTo(getterFunction.apply(o1));
        }
        return (o1, o2) -> getterFunction.apply(o1).compareTo(getterFunction.apply(o2));
    }

}
```

The call would look something like

```
list.stream().sorted(sort(YourClass::getSortProperty, true));
```

Answer (score 2):

Most concise:

```
Collections.sort(stringList, String::compareToIgnoreCase);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have an array with elements that have natural ordering (i.e `String`, `int`, `double`); then it can be achieved by:

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();
myList.add("A");
myList.add("D");
myList.add("C");
myList.add("B");
myList.sort(Comparator.comparing(s -> s));
myList.forEach(System.out::println);
```

If on the another hand you have an array of objects and you want to sort base on some sort of object field, then you can use:

```
class User {
    double score;
    // Constructor // Getters // Setters
}

List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
users.add(new User(19d));
users.add(new User(67d));
users.add(new User(50d));
users.add(new User(91d));

List<User> sortedUsers = users
        .stream()
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(User::getScore))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

sortedUsers.forEach(System.out::println);
```

If the sorting is more complex, then you would have to write your own comparator and pass that in.

Answer (score 1):

```
 List<Product> list = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(new Product(1));
        list.add(new Product(2));
        list.add(new Product(3));
        list.add(new Product(10));
 Collections.sort(list, Comparator.comparing((Product p) -> p.id));
        for (Product p : list) {
            System.out.println(p.id);
        }
```

Comment: Sticking to functional programming, for (Product p : list) {
            System.out.println(p.id);
        } can be written as list.stream().forEach(System.out::println);

Answer (score 0):

The syntax including a custom comparator is quite simple, and quick, for example here the ArrayList being sorted contains JSONObjects, and I will sort it based on a property called 'order':

```
arrayList.sort((JSONObject o1, JSONObject o2)->o1.getInt("order")-o2.getInt("order"));
```

I think this is a really nice and concise syntax, easy to read and less bulky than non-lambda syntax.

Answer (score 0):

To sort ArrayList of String in n descending order just
refer to this type And if You are looking for ascending then replace a1 with a2.

```
Collections.sort(ArrayListName,(a1,a2)->a2.compareTo(a1));
```